# Display a variable value in a text box in JSP

Tags: jsp

I use the following code to read a bar code scanned value from a bar code scanner in a JSP

```
<%
    final Scanner scanner;

    try 
    {
        scanner = new Scanner();

        try {
            scanner.release();
            scanner.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        scanner.open("MotorolaScannerUSB");

        scanner.claim(100);
        scanner.setDeviceEnabled(true);
        scanner.setDataEventEnabled(true);

        scanner.addDataListener(new DataListener() 
        {
            public void dataOccurred(DataEvent arg0) {
                Scanner scn = (Scanner) arg0.getSource();

                if (scn.equals(scanner)) {                      
                    try {
                        scanner.claim(100);
                        System.out.println(new String(scanner.getScanData()));
                        scanner.claim(100);
                        scanner.setDeviceEnabled(true);
                        scanner.setDataEventEnabled(true);
                    } catch (JposException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("error");
    }
%>
```

I configured the scanner and it is successfully been opened and also when I scan a code it is been printed to the console, but now I want to display the scanned code in a text box filed in the JSP, but I don't know how, any idea

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
System.out.println(new String(scanner.getScanData()));
```

by

```
request.setAttribute("scanData", new String(scanner.getScanData()));
```

so that you can just do later in the very same JSP

```
<input type="text" value="${fn:escapeXml(scanData)}" />
```

Or, if you have no idea how to use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)/[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), or can't use it for some unclear reason (even though they are since a decade the officially recommended way of writing JSPs), use

```
String scanData = new String(scanner.getScanData());
```

and

```
<input type="text" value="<%= scanData %>" />
```

*(note that scriptlets have no builtin HTML escaping facilities, take this into account when preventing potential XSS attack holes)*

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, all that Java code design technically belongs in a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) class, not in a JSP file.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use ajax and have the client send a request for any new bar codes scanned to your server and then return a json object with the most recent bar-code. Check out [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for your client side data processing.